# Looping 3 unpack values through a dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

So this is my following code:

```
users = {
    'Bernard':'Is this a dream?':'No.',
    'Suzy':'What is your favorite color?':'Purple',
    'Matthew':'In what city were you born?':'Cullowhee',
    }




for user,question,answer in users.items():
    print("User: " + user)
    print("Question: " + question)
    print("Answer: " + answer)
```

my main issue is that it argues I don't have enough values to unpack(I need 3, not 2), and my only problem is I am not sure how to do that.

I need my output to look like this:
User: Bernard
Question: Is this a dream?
Answer: No.

User: Suzy
Question: What is your favorite color?
Answer: Purple

User: Matthew
Question: In which city where you born?
Answer: Cullowhee

Thank you in advance for any pointers or tips I can get!

Comment: your input `users` is not a valid python syntax. can you check it? a dictionary has 1 value per key so 1 colon, not 2.

Comment: guessing that it should be: `for user,(question,answer) in users.items()`

Comment: Hm, thank for the response, because it is looping through, I really want to be able to get the third line for the answer, I am just not sure how to go about that in the dictionary, again, thank you so much, I am kind of in the starting stages of learning Python

Comment: Also, I did note that it could only have 1 value per key, I am supposed to have 3 keys per dictionary, which are the user, question, and answer for the users

Comment: your question cannot be answered as long as the input "dictionary" is a syntax error